# Changing the marker icon using android-maps-extensions

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-extensions

I moved to [android-maps-extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) for clustering. But I want to change the icons of the markers during runtime. In the original google maps lib markers have a [setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setIcon%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor%29) method, that is missing in the extension lib. Would it be feasible to add the method to the Marker implementation or should I look for another workaround like deleting the marker and add a new one instead of changing the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.3.1 you can directly download from the project site, didn't have `setIcon` added.

The currect status is version 1.4 is about to be released and it includes both `setIcon` and `setAnchor`. I have some problems with uploading zip file to code.google.com.

If you don't want to use git to clone the repository, you may grab the latest version from GitHub repo: https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/archive/master.zip

Note that `setIcon` will only work for `Marker`s you add to the map. You will not be able to change clusters icons this way for now.

**Edit:**

Changing `ClusterMarker.setIcon` code from

```java
@Override
public void setIcon(BitmapDescriptor icon) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

to something like:

```java
@Override
public void setIcon(BitmapDescriptor icon) {
    if (virtual != null) {
        virtual.setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

should work in most cases.

Comment: Works. Any idea how to achieve this also for cluster markers? Maybe `IconDataProvider` could be used for that?

Comment: @comatic Depending on when you want to change the icon. If it's after the cluster `Marker` is created, then see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve a custom clustering icon

Do this ..........

```java
for (Cluster cluster : clusterList) {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.cluster_marker, options);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    paint.setTextSize(30);

    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(cluster.getMarkerList().size()), 10,
            40, paint);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(
                    new LatLng(cluster.getClusterLatitude(), cluster
                            .getClusterLongitude()))
            .snippet(String.valueOf(cluster.getMarkerList().size()))
            .title("Cluster")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));

}
```

where cluster marker is my drawable and I'm writing text over it.